# msvc + GNU make

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, build, gnu-make

I understand that the fastest and the most lightweight binary at windows generate only msvc compiler

Express edition of msvc is free
http://www.microsoft.com/express/windows/

but how to use cl.exe instead of g++.exe?

is it possible in common by using GNU make variables produce makefiles which will works with cl.exe and g++?

for example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy(v=VS.80).aspx

```
export CC = path/to/cl.exe
export COMPILE_WITHOUT_LINKING = /c
export OBJECT_FILE = /Fo
```

or is conception of cl and g++ very different?

Comment: -1 for incorrect initial assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can. `cl.exe` is just another command line tool. However, the two compilers differ in more advanced usage, so it might be difficult to use `cl.exe` as a drop-in replacement for `g++`.

Answer (score 5):

Make (GNU make or otherwise) can be used to run whatever programs you like for generating files. It's an abstract dependency generation system which is entirely language-agnostic. However, if you're trying to take an existing project that uses standard POSIX-style compiler/linker command lines, and make it use MSVC's `cl.exe`, you're probably going to run into a lot of problems with incompatible command line syntax, not to mention the fact that `cl.exe` is still struggling to conform to the ancient standards it purports to support, much less C99.

All in all, gcc is certainly a much better choice to use, if you have the choice.